# When getting values from a list ,the same function doesn't fetch data twice?(python)

Tags: list, python-2.7, iterator

```
>>> movement = ((x,y)for x in range(-1,2) for y in range (-1,2) if (x,y)!=(0,0))
>>> for x,y in movement:
        print x,y


-1 -1
-1 0
-1 1
0 -1
0 1
1 -1
1 0
1 1
>>> for a,b in movement:
        print a,b


>>> for x,y in movement:
        print x,y


>>>
```

THis is happening in terminal and idle both (Am i doing something wrong or is this supposed to happen?)

Comment: Not function , same code is not fetching it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a `generator` object (https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). This means that you can iterate over it exactly once - that's why the first time it works as advertised.

Change the movement 'maker' to this and it works; now it creates a *list*, not a `generator`.

```
movement = [(x,y)for x in range(-1,2) for y in range (-1,2) if (x,y)!=(0,0)]
```

To elaborate a bit; on the linked page it sais this:

> In fact, we can turn a list comprehension into a generator expression
>   by replacing the square brackets ("[ ]") with parentheses.